# iOS gyro error when rotating about z-axis

Tags: javascript, ios, orientation, calibration

I am having trouble solving a strange bug I've come across and was wondering if anyone else has had a similar issue or can offer a solution.

I am using javascript to access the gyro an iOS devices and am interested in rotation around the z-axis; I want the angle of rotation while the device is lying flat on a table.

However the gyro seems to be off by about 20deg for every 360deg of rotation. If I align the device with something on the table then rotate the device 360deg, returning it to it's starting point, the angle reading is ~340deg rather the 360 or 0. This is compounding so after 1080deg of rotation the angle is off by ~60deg, if I then rotate in the reverse direction it reverses the error (in this case after -1080deg of rotation it will return to 0deg).

I have tested this on an Ipad 2, 3 and iPhone 4 and it have seen a similar problem on all of them - although the iPhone is more like 8deg out for every 360deg. I have also tried using libraries like gyro.js but the same result occurs.

I have put together a short codepen example to demonstrate.
http://codepen.io/CharlesSmart/pen/ZYNXEJ?editors=101

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', orientationHandler, false);
function orientationHandler(e)
{
var alpha = e.alpha
var div = document.getElementById('text');
div.innerHTML = alpha;
}
```

Am I misusing the orientation api in some way? Could this be a problem with the devices I'm using?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My bet is that you are getting accelerometer data, not gyro data.

You probably want "devicemotion" not "deviceorientation".